# CSS :after-icon on :hover makes box bigger

Tags: css, hover, nav

I am having trouble figuring out the solution for a problem regarding adding an icon on `:hover`in the `:after` pseudo-class to list-items in a navbar.

The appended icon will always make the navbar "wobble" on `:hover` since the box of the icon is larger than the list-items ones. I can see what causes the problem, but am not versed enough to come up with a fix. Btw: making the icon smaller is not a desired option in this case...

```css
* {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav a:hover:after {
  content: ' ⚒';
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;'
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Suggestions anyone? I'm sure this is a quick fix for you guys.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `line-height to 0` on hover.That would fix the issue.Here is the code

```css
.nav {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav a:hover:after {
  content: ' ⚒';
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot karthik, that was the solution I was searching for. Have a great day!